# Python longest character sequence in a string

Tags: python, string, character

I'm studying python and got an issue with a lab. Need to calculate the longest sequence of an `s` char in a string, can only use basic tools like for loops.

The code that I've come up with works, but it feels like I'm using an inappropriate logics adding a `sequence_extended` variable with an extra space. However without this extension provided the sequence is e.g. `sssdssss` the calculation only works for the first sequence.

Might there be a way to avoid that extension? I've tried looking for an idea, but the solution is usually to use the functions we're not allowed to use yet, such as lists etc.

```
sequence = input('enter a line: ')
sequence_extended = sequence + ' '
counter = 0
final_counter = 0

for symbol in sequence_extended:
  if symbol == 's':
    counter += 1
    
  else:
    if counter > final_counter:
        final_counter = counter
        counter = 0


print("The longest sequence of 's':", final_counter)
```

Comment: You're not allowed to use dictionaries right?

Comment: @Mick aye, exactly

Comment: It's an easy question, hold on

Comment: You need to add a line for what happens if the last symbol is an "s". As you have it now, final counter is only updated if the last character is not an "s" ( why adding the extra space at the end fixes it).

Comment: are you allowed to use a while loop? I can make it a for loop instead if not

Comment: @Mick yep, certainly. For loops, while loops, ifs are at our disposal

Comment: @goalie1998 exactly, that's why I've added an extended version of line with a space. I'll try and add a condition to properly update the final counter, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sequence = "sssdssss"
max_len = 0

for i in range(len(sequence)):
    if sequence[i] == "s":
        j = i
        length = 0
        while j < len(sequence) and sequence[j] == "s":
            length += 1
            j += 1
        if length > max_len:
            max_len = length

print("The longest sequence of 's':", max_len)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Totally works and I get the logics. Appreciate it!

Comment: No problem, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, I've come up with an even less complicated option:

```
sequence = input('enter a sequence: ')

first_counter = 0
second_counter = 0

for symbol in sequence:
  if symbol == 's':
    first_counter += 1
  if symbol != 's':
    first_counter = 0  
  if second_counter < first_counter:
    second_counter = first_counter
print("the longest sequence of 's':", second_counter)
```

It seems to be an optimal solution for the matter. Just in case someone else has a lab like this to solve.